# How to find documents with nodejs and mongoose, why there is no result?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There is 3 documents in person collection, but I can't find()

mongodb shell:

```
> use test;
switched to db test
> db.person.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("527f18f7d0ec1e35065763e4"), "name" : "aaa", "sex" : "man", "height" : 180 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("527f1903d0ec1e35065763e5"), "name" : "bbb", "sex" : "man", "height" : 160 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("527f190bd0ec1e35065763e6"), "name" : "ccc", "sex" : "woman", "height" : 160 }
```

my nodejs code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://uuu:ppp@localhost:27017/test');
//mongoose.set('debug', true);

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
    console.log("connection success!");
    mongoose.model('person', mongoose.Schema({ name: String}),'person');

    var out = db.model('person');
    //console.log(out);
    out.find({},function(err, obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        console.log(1);
    });
});
```

But, the result is :
    connection success!
    []
    1

Comment: What if you define all the fields in the schema? Eg: `mongoose.Schema({ name: String, sex: String, height: Number})`? I think mongoose uses some magic to determine if a document belongs to your model or not.

Comment: @AndreasHultgren the result is still the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that when you use `createConnection`, you need to use the `.model` method of the created connection, instead of `mongoose.model`:

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection(...);

// wrong:
mongoose.model('person', mongoose.Schema({ name: String}),'person');

// right:
db.model('person', mongoose.Schema({ name: String}),'person');

// perform query:
db.model('person').find(...);
```

The reason is that, as far as I understand, a model is 'associated' to a connection. When you use `mongoose.model`, the model is associated to the default connection, but you're not using that (you're using a connection that you create explicitly with `createConnection`).

Another way to show this is using `modelNames`:

```
// wrong:
mongoose.model('person', mongoose.Schema({ name: String}),'person');
console.log('default conn models:', mongoose.modelNames()); // -> [ 'person' ]
console.log('custom  conn models:', db.modelNames());       // -> []

// right:
db.model('person', mongoose.Schema({ name: String}),'person');
console.log('default conn models:', mongoose.modelNames()); // -> []
console.log('custom  conn models:', db.modelNames());       // -> [ 'person' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not putting your find statement inside the callback for connection.

Try to put it here:

```
db.once('open', function callback () {
    console.log("connection success!");

    mongoose.model('person', mongoose.Schema({ name: String}), 'person');

    db.model('person').find({name:'aaa'},function(err, obj) {
      console.log(obj);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you put also console.log(1); after console.log(obj); and tell me the output of the script? Is it "connection success" and then "1"? Also try to put .find({}) there to see if it finds documents at all?

Comment: @Abrother and you are actually a different person then the OP :-)

Comment: I  modify like this：
db.once('open', function callback () {
    console.log("connection success!");
    mongoose.model('person', mongoose.Schema({ name: String}),'person');

    var out = db.model('person');
    out.find({},function(err, obj) {   
        console.log(obj);
        console.log(1);
    });
});
The result：
connection success!
[]
1

Comment: @Abrother In such a case, I don't know where is the problem. Sorry.

Comment: I only want to realize like a sql: 'select * from person'. can you give me a simple example. Thank you.

Comment: @Abrother the problem that I am not a mongoose developer, but because there is no one else who tried to answer - check this [blog](http://blog.modulus.io/getting-started-with-mongoose): looks like a step by step explanation

Comment: The code works fine when I use it to query my own MongoDB collection. I'd check the results of `console.log(out)` to see whether it's picking up the model from the DB. If it is then the query should work fine. Although as SD says, you should remove the query initially to see whether that is the issue.

Comment: @Michael  console.log(out):  { [Function: Model]
  db: 
   { base: 
      { connections: [Object],
        plugins: [],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object] },
     collections: { people: [Object] },
     models: { person: [Circular] },
     replica: false,
     hosts: null,
     host: 'localhost',
     port: 27017,
     user: 'uuu',
     pass: 'ppp',
     name: 'test',
     options: ......

Comment: @Abrother I think the issue may be linked to the fact that the collection is called 'people' when due to your naming of it it should just be called 'person' as far as I can tell. With my setup I don't pass a collection name through so my 'Photo' model just becomes 'photos' as the collection. I suggest you look into where 'people' has come from and also remove the collection name string as the third argument when instantiating the mongoose model.

Comment: @Michael he's explicitly stating which collection to use in the call to `mongoose.Model`

Comment: Oh I see. Apologies. I thought from http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model that that option was to allow you to explicitly set the name rather than stating which collection to use.

Comment: @Abrother like Michael, I can't reproduce the problem either. Is the code you posted the actual code you test with, and the DB the actual DB?

Comment: @robertklep Yes. I had test on two machines, and the result is the same. Can you give a printscreen to your test result?

Comment: @Abrother see my answer, figured out your problem

Comment: @robertklep Thank you so much. I love you.